# How to send data from the backend to the frontend in a wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress plugin, and I created a form in the admin panel I want to take the data from that form and pass it to my Frontend javascript file. Is it possible to do it, and if it is how do I do that?

```html
<div id="wrap container">
        <h3 id="eylon"> Plugin Header </h3>
    
     <form method="post" action='options.php'>
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>
        <?php settings_fields('my_plugin_option_group'); ?>
        <label for="jquery-field">select field ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="jquery-field" id="jquery-field" value="<?php echo get_option('jquery-field');?> ">
        <?php submit_button();?>

    </form> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can refer to the listen handle from the server every few seconds to catch changes from the back-end via ajax that works the same protocol.